# Picture box to byte array

Tags: c#, image, arrays, picturebox

I have a program to select an image and to set that selected image in a picture box then convert the image in the image box to byte array and save sql server data base in a image type column.

In browse button click event I'm selecting the image file like this.

```
OpenFileDialog fop = new OpenFileDialog();
fop.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
fop.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";
if (fop.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     FileStream FS = new FileStream(@fop.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
     pbPartySymbol.Image = new Bitmap(fop.FileName);
     MessageBox.Show("Image Imported Successfully!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

After selecting the image and setting it the picture box image I'm converting the picture box image to byte array in the save button click event and saving the byte array to database.

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

I'm calling the method like this.

```
byte[] myArr1 = imageToByteArray(pbPartySymbol.Image);
```

and I'm passing this byte array to the data base. and it saves too. But *ALL* the added images are saved as like this.* 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D* Saved images cannot be get back to the picture box in the reading operation. What am I doing wrong in the *SAVING*?

Here's what I do in saving operation in the form.

```
            Party ptObj = new Party(myArr1);
            if (new PartyOP().saveParty(ptObj))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NEW data added");
            }
```

In my business operation layer this is my code.

```
          public Boolean saveParty(Party ptObj)
         {
          string query1 = "EXEC insertToParty'" + ptObj.PTSymARR + "'";
           return (new DataAccessLayer().executeNonQueries(query1));
        }
```

Here's how I have set the property in the Party class.

```
class Party
{
    public Party() { }
    public Party(byte[] ptSym) 
    {

        this._PTSymARR = ptSym;

    }
    public byte[] PTSymARR
    {
        get { return _PTSymARR; }
        set { _PTSymARR = value; }
    }


}
```

here's my stored procedure.
      CREATE PROCEDURE insertToParty
   (
      @ptSymbol image
  )
    AS 
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
      --Query
    INSERT INTO Party(PTSYM) 
       VALUES (@ptSymbol);

Data type of PTSYM is image data type.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, at least as far as i can see. how is the db column defined and how do you read it back, and what happens there?

Comment: @TaW I have a stored procedure to add. I just call it and pass the parameter list. 

public Boolean saveParty(Party ptObj)
        {
            string query1 = "EXEC insertToParty'" + ptObj.PTSymARR + "'";
            return (new DataAccessLayer().executeNonQueries(query1));
        } Here I'm passing the byte array as object property.

The thing is all saved images in the DB looks like this
0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D

Comment: I'm lost.  It's a `Byte[]`, and you're saving it.  What do you expect to see?  If you want it back to an image later, reverse the process.

Comment: What is the DB data type, and what DBMS do you use?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Nothing to see . PLEASE READ> ALL the saved image records in the DB  shows this record, 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D. It can't be the same for all the records. Because I didn't save same image.

Comment: @TaW. It's given in the question. SQL SERVER and Image data type.

Comment: Is that all that is saved? The fileheaders should be the same if the files have the same format, size..

Comment: @TaW Yes that's all it saves.

Comment: Your question, as written, is useless.  You show image and byte array handling, but you are really asking about database save/load operations.  Rewrite it showing the appropriate code.  No one can help you as it is.

Comment: try to set the debugger on the `byte[] myArr1 = imageToByteArray(pbPartySymbol.Image);` line and check the length of that array!

Comment: What is the length of `myArr1` ?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Is it detailed enough now?

Comment: @TaW Length of the array is 12689

Comment: OK, that seems like a plausible length. Sorry to ask for 'even more details' but how is that read back and converted to an image? If all those byte are in the DB ()are they??), the problem seems to be in retrieving and displaying it..

Comment: @TaW yes yes 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D this value is in data base not the form level. All the image records I get from the SELECT * FROM Party; shows that value. How come there be a problem in the DB? Shouldn't it be the saving method?  That's why I'm saying there should be a problem in saving. I edited the question. Please go through it again whether I have set the values for the property in the class file correct.

Comment: OK, if these few byte all that is in the DB, then indeed the saving is wrong. Do try Stephan's solution..

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic query strings, ever. Try to find out if your DataAccessLayer allows parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Hex string tranlates to `System.Byte[]`.

You add the Byte-Array to the string starting with `EXEC insertToParty` so .Net assumes you want a string representation of that variable. Unless specified it calls .ToString wich gives you .... "System.Byte[]".

Edit: Your stored procedure does not use hex encoding on insert. `image` data shows in hex when viewed in SQL Studio etc.

If you would encode your byte array to a string using base64 or hex when inserting and decode that when you read the data you only had to worry about the increased storage, but I recommend that you change your db acces from a dynamic SELECT to a prepared statement with parameters:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Exec InsertToParty(@blob)");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blob", ptObj.PTSymARR);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Stored procedure is a must, Isn't there anyway that I can edit this without removing the stored procedure.

Comment: any code examples? I added my store procedure code too if you need to check.